# assertRegExp phpunit & selenium can't read integer value

Tags: php, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I have a question relating to automating tests using phpunit and selenium.  The tab I want to test displays text and an integer, eg. 'All Open (56)' where the integer can change depending on the # of records it has.  I have a test case which tests the text on this menu Tab:

```
public function testHasAllOpenTab()
{
    $this->url('index.php'); // Set the URL to test
    // check for the existence of the strin 'All Open'
    $this->assertRegExp( '/All Open/i', $this->source() );        
}
```

But what I would like is to test that the text contains a number from 0 - 100 aswell.
I have tried:
    $this->assertRegExp('/All Open (/(s*0,\s*255)/', $element->source());

But I still get errors.  Can anyone help please?
Thanks
Conor

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$this->assertRegExp( '/All Open \((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\)/i', $this->source() );
```

- `\d` - all one digit
- `[1-9]\d` - all two digits strats not from 0
- `1\d\d` - all 1**
- `2[0-4]\d` - all 20*,21*,22*,23*,24*
- `25[0-5]` - and 250,251,252,253,254,255